# linking to photos app/camera roll from my app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've looked around the internet about this but couldn't seem to find much information, is there any way that I can have users press a button on my app that will close my app and open up the Photos app/camera roll? I know that this is technically possible but I have no idea if Apple has allowed developers this sort of access.

Comment: You can access the user's photo library or take photos from within your app, is that what you mean to do? I'm not sure why you'd want to open the "photo" app separately, and I do not think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the photo picker to show the user their library and take pictures, but there is no public URL scheme that you could use to open the Photos app.

Comment: More or less what I figured, but I just wanted to double check and be sure. Thanks!